# Get the correct value of a variable

Tags: ios, react-native

When i try to get the value of 'isFullVersionBought' by using this code - everything is perfect:

```
inApp1.get('isFullVersionBought').then((data) => {console.log("What is the value?: ", data)});
```

This code returns me 'What is the value?: ', 'Yes'

But when i use variable for this code - it returns me the wrong value.
This is my code of variable (+ console):

```
let fullversionbought = inApp1.get('isFullVersionBought').then((data) => {data});
console.log(fullversionbought);
```

This code returns me { _45: 0, _81: 1, _65: 'Yes', _54: null }

Why? 
How to get the value 'Yes'?

Comment: Read about Javascript Promise to understand what's going on here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting fullversionbought before the request is completed so an incomplete value is getting logged. Try this

```
inApp1.get('isFullVersionBought').then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    let fullversionbought = data;
    // Do whatever you need with this value now that the req completed.
});
```

Comment: But how i can use this variable **'fullversionbought'** outside this function? I tried this code, but it doesn't work: `inApp1.get('isFullVersionBought').then((data) => {
    let fullversionbought = data;
    return fullversionbought;
});` - I use this variable in many js files and i need it could be used outside this function.

Comment: Like what @maxpaj said in the comment to your question, definitely read up on the docs on JS promises. There's no guarantee that fullversionbought will have a boolean value as you expect with the current method declaration you have (what happens if the network request fails for example?). By using promises you can have completion handlers containing the value for fullversionbought or lack thereof in any of your other js files.